# Trigger value converter re-evaluation

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to trigger all value converters of a certain class to re-evaluate?

I'm asking this because I'm currently trying to figure out a nice way of doing localization, specifically having a dictionary of translated strings.

Example is as follows:

Value converter:

```
export class TValueConverter {
  static inject() { return [Dictionary] }

  dictionary: Dictionary;

  constructor(dictionary: Dictionary) {
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
  }

  toView(key: string, replacements: any): string {
    return this.dictionary.translate(key, replacements);
  }
}
```

view:

```
<template>
  <p>${"hello_world" | t: {"name": "Some User"} }</p>
</template>
```

This would then be converted to

```
<p>
Hello Some User!
</p>
```

But, the user can change the current language, and when they do, I would like to re-evaluate this value conversion using the new language.

My implementation is inspired by https://github.com/zewa666/aurelia-i18next, but their solution is to add ": currentLanguage" to the value converter in order to introduce the dependency, which works, but feels repetitive since I will have to inject the dictionary into every view model in order to make the "currentLanguage" variable available to the view.

Can I signal from the TValueConverter class, that it has a dependency on dictionary.lang, or otherwise trigger it using an event?

Comment: signals are coming in the release after next, keep an eye on this issue:  https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/issues/25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed solved with the coming of signals

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/5